# Why I am getting selected index -1 before binding it with dataset in C# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdown

[image]

I am having problem while binding a drop down list with data set which gets only one row with priviously entered value. I want the selected value of drop down list to be 1 which was selected earlier through drop down list

Comment: A Dataset will have zero items until the constructor creates tables and columns in tables.

Comment: Please add your codes in text format.